# Sorting dataframe based on data chunk separators

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I would like perform sorting on the dataframe that consists of chunks of data separated with rows. Sorting should be performed on every chunk of data separately, so that I would get the biggest value of let's say Column 2. Here is an example:

| ID | Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Case 1 |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| Case 2 |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

I was wondering if there is any possibility to perform such sorting and then to get rows with highest value in each case? I would like to have the result that looks like this:

| ID | Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Case 1 |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Case 2 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| Summary |  |  |
| Case | ID | Value of column 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |

Is there any possiblity of doing this in Pandas, or do I need to use xarray for that? If xarray needs to be used, then is there any clever way translating dataframe to xarray object? I've tried to move dataframe to xarray, however I don't quite understand how that works.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom aggregation with [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
m = df['Column 1'].notna()
group = df['ID'].mask(m).ffill()

idx = df[m].groupby(group)['Column 2'].idxmax()

out = pd.concat([df,
                 pd.DataFrame([['Summary'],
                               ['Case', 'ID', 'Value of column 2']],
                              columns=df.columns),
                 df.loc[idx].assign(Case=group)
                    [['Case', 'ID', 'Column 2']]
                   .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)],
                ignore_index=True
                ).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
         ID Column 1           Column 2
0    Case 1                            
1         1      1.0                7.0
2         2      2.0                2.0
3         3      3.0                4.0
4    Case 2                            
5         1      1.0                4.0
6         2      2.0                6.0
7         3      3.0                3.0
8   Summary                            
9      Case       ID  Value of column 2
10   Case 1        1                7.0
11   Case 2        2                6.0
```